# Disable 3G on iPhone 5 with iOS8

Tags: iphone, ios

After the update to iOS8, the switch to disable the 3G has been replaced by a disable 4G switch.

4G is already off but how could I also disable also 3G (which is still active, as shown on the status bar)

Answer (score -1):

iOS 8.1 which will most probably be released on 20 Oct will fix the issue by adding the ability to select between 2G, 3G and LTE

Comment: Do you have a source for this? Without a source this is speculative and will be deleted.